# run('PyTest') failed in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have the following Python code that requieres PyTest to be installed:

```
run([
    'pytest', 'my_tests.py',
    '--option1', "value1",
    '--option2', "value2"
])
```

to make it work from the command line on Windows I did this:

```
python -m venv venv
.\venv\Scripts\activate
python -m pip install
```

then I installed PyCharm and tried to run my code, but it failed with the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

What should I do in PyCharm to make it work?